# IOException on reading large files

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Here is my code for writting file from one file to another. It works fine for file having size less than 2GB but throws exception when it is of greater size. So it copies less than 2 gb data and then throws exception after that. Any fixes?

```
const int bufferSize = 2048;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int bytes = 0;
using (var input = filedata.DataStream)
using (var output = ServiceModel.FileManager.Current.GetFile(filedata.FileName).Open(FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    while ((bytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) //Throws exception: An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: You state that you are only going to write to the file, then you read from it.

Comment: Which type are "output " and "input"? 'var' doesn't help here... Can you paste the exact exception you have?